# Should I urlencode ampersands?

Tags: php

Should I also be urlencoding the ampersands separating my parameters when doing a GET request or is this not necessary? See my code below

```
$DialerIntegrationFirstName = urlencode(trim($data->FirstName));
$DialerIntegrationLastName = urlencode(trim($data->LastName));
$DialerIntegrationMobilePhone = urlencode(trim($data->MobilePhone));
$DialerIntegrationEmail = urlencode(trim($data->Email));

$curl_url = "https://url.com?firstname=$DialerIntegrationFirstName&lastname=$DialerIntegrationLastName&phone=$DialerIntegrationMobilePhone&email=$DialerIntegrationEmail";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$curl_info = json_encode($curl_info);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Usually not, but it also depends on how the server script handles this URL. Can't you just try it yourself and make it clear?